# .htaccess RewriteCond for images in another folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Yes, yet another RewriteCond, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to get it to work....

I have the Apache root as `/var/www/html/`, and and if I go to `http://example.com/` it correctly uses `/var/www/html/index.php`.

Now, the problem is that I have the images in `/var/www/images/example.com/`.  This is because I have a multi-site setup that needs to be dynamic.  PHP will sort out which site's code is used, so moving the images or aliasing them is not an option as it needs to be dynamic.

So, I have something like this in my `/var/www/html/.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond /var/www/images/example.com%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /var/www/images/example.com/$1 # <--- this DOES fire when the image exists

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /var/www/html/test.php?file=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [END]
```

The `test.php` just echos `$_GET`, and the strange thing is that `$_GET['file']` is `/var/www/html/var`

What am I doing wrong?!

---

## Update

Ok, so now I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sites/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I changed it so that the site files are inside the main server root.  Now I can't get it to not allow direct access to the files.

What I want is this:

http://example.com/images/fb.png -> /var/www/sites/example.com/images/fb.png
http://example.com/sites/example.com/images/fb.png -> /var/www/index.php (to show 404)
http://example.com/whatever -> /var/www/index.php

As you can see, the second line file is the full-direct path to the file, and **should pass off to index.php**, but instead it just sends the file.  How to I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't rewrite to something that isn't in your document root (for obvious security reasons, otherwise people would just inject stuff to rewrite to `/etc/passwd`). That means you can't do anything about anything that's not in `/var/www/html/`. What you'll need to do is use a script that can access files outside of the document root. Maybe something like:

```
RewriteCond /var/www/images/example.com%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /image_serve.php?img=example.com/$1 [L]
```

And then, the `image_serve.php` script would do something like:

```
 <?php
  if (substr($_GET['img'], -strlen('.png')) === '.png')
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
  else if (substr($_GET['img'], -strlen('.gif')) === '.gif')
    header("Content-Type: image/gif");
  else if (substr($_GET['img'], -strlen('.jpg')) === '.jpg')
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

  readfile('/var/www/images/' . $_GET['img']);
?>
```

Comment: Ok, that explains it.

Comment: However, I do not want to use PHP for every image, as it's much faster to have APACHE load them.  I'll figure something out, thanks.

Comment: Even after moving the images into the `/var/www/html/` I still get the same strange redirect issues.

Comment: @Sarke what redirect issues?

Comment: `/var/www/html/var` issue.  I think I have it figured out though, I will post my answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This does what I want.

```
# rewrite to site subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sites/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,QSD,DPI]

# if file doesn't exists in subfolder, just pass it to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [END]

# prevent another go-around
RewriteRule .* - [END]
```